# How to get searched item value in search form?

Tags: 7, search

How do I get the value of searched item value, if I searched for "cat" in a search box then it also displays on a search page?

Comment: How do you want to use it?

Comment: Just need to display it like in a variable

Answer (score 0):

You can catch your entity in the preprocess and put data into drupal_static. After that you can display it where you want.

Answer (score 0):

This way sometimes works, in a hook_alter function:

```
if ($form_id == 'search_form'){
  // gives you the value
  $save_value = $form['basic']['keys']["#default_value"];
}
```

But this way seems to work even better:

```
\Drupal::request()->query->get('keys')
```

There should technically also be a way of making a custom module, add a custom submit handler to the search form, and getting the value in there, but I couldn't get it working that way.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention the second part. To display on your search results page, override the search-results twig template and use the variable from the .theme file.

Answer (score 0):

Though I am seriously late to the party, you can also grab the query thusly if you use the Search API module. After you created a View associated to your search index, you can use:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_views_view()
 * @param $variables
 */
function YOUR_THEME_NAME_preprocess_views_view(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['view']->id() == 'search') {
        $variables['search_keywords'] = \Drupal::request()->query->get('search_api_fulltext');
  }
}
```

In this case, my view is named "search" and the query key I am looking for (after the ?) is "search_api_fulltext" (id of my input search field).

$variables['search_keywords'] will now contain the keywords after the "=", for instance from /search?search_api_fulltext=searched+term